# Python Dask - Read multiple files with different column names

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I have 12 files corresponding to each month of the year.
They have MultipleIndexes and one column whose name is the given month.

**January File**

```
                    Jan
index_0 | index_1 | 

bla     | bla     |   3
```

**February File**

```
                    Feb
index_0 | index_1 | 

bla     | bla     |   2
```

I would like to read those files like that :

```
df = dd.read_csv(
    location + "*.txt", 
    sep=';',
    header=0
)
```

**Output**

```
                    Jan
index_0 | index_1 | 

bla     | bla     |   3
bla     | bla     |   2
```

The problem is I lose a piece of information, I don't have the month anymore.

**Expected output**

```
                    Month  | Value
index_0 | index_1 | 

bla     | bla     |   Jan        3
bla     | bla     |   Feb        2
```

How can I keep the month in my dataframe ?

Comment: read your file into a list , then using concat

Comment: it does the job but I wondered if there is a way to avoid for loops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want custom behaviour beyond what `read_csv` provides, you should turn to `dask.delayed`:

```
def load_func(fn):

    df = pd.read_csv(
        location + "*.txt", 
        sep=';',
        header=0
    )
    df['month'] = df.columns[0]
    df.columns = ['value', 'month']
    return df


ddf = dd.from_delayed([dask.delayed(load_func)(fn) for fn in files])
```